# Common folder in linux

Tags: permissions, shared-folders

I have two users on my Ubuntu machine.  I want to share some media files between these users, so I created a directory in /home/ called 'media'.  I made the group 'media' and I added my user 'rks171' to the group 'media'.  So:

```
sudo groupadd media
sudo mkdir -p /home/media
sudo chown -R root.media /home/media 
sudo chmod g+s /home/media
```

As was described in [this post.](https://superuser.com/questions/88874/where-on-a-linux-file-system-should-someone-put-media-intended-to-be-accessible)

Then, I added my user to the group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G media rks171
```

Then I also added write permission to this folder for my group:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w media
```

So now, doing 'ls -lh' gives:

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 root   media  4.0K Oct  6 09:46 media
```

I tried to copy pictures to this new directory from my user directory:

```
mv /home/rks171/Pictures/* /home/media/
```

And I get 'permission denied'.  I can't understand what's wrong.

If I simply type, 'id', it doesn't show that my user, rks171, is part of the 'media' group.  But if I type, 'id rks171', then it does show that my user, rks171, is part of the 'media' group.  Anybody have any ideas why I can't get an files into this common folder?

Comment: Did you log in **after** adding yourself to the group? Or are you using your old session from before the changes?

Comment: That was the problem.  I'll update it with the answer.  Thanks a lot Hennes.

Answer (score 1):

As Hennes pointed out in the comment section, I needed to restart my session by logging out and back in before the settings would take effect.  Everything works fine now.